# How to fix this specified cast which throws an exception

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is my code

```
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Meeting.StartPlan " +
                "FROM Meeting " +
                "INNER JOIN meetingWho ON Meeting.meetingID = meetingWho.meetingID" +
                " and Who= '"+ Username +"'  ", con);
            SqlDataReader read = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (read.HasRows)
            {
                while (read.Read())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}/t{1}", read.GetInt32(0), read.GetString(1));
                    if (e.Day.DayNumberText == "read.GetInt32(0)")
                    {
                        e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                    }
               }
            }</i>
```

and it gives error at this line

```
  Console.WriteLine("{0}/t{1}", read.GetInt32(0), read.GetString(1));
```

what should I do to fix this ?

Comment: You need to remove the double quotes from `if (e.Day.DayNumberText == read.GetInt32(0))` as well!

Comment: please practice to use EF or stored procedures, this is too old school

Comment: @Katana you are of course entitled to your opinion, but there are still good reasons to use plain ADO.NET. Apart from that, you do have a potential SQL injection issue by just using `Username` in the query, you should use parameterized queries.

Comment: @Christian.K yah there is no benchmark for that. I just find convenience when coding with EF

Answer (score 2):

`read.GetString(1)` will throw this error because in your `SELECT` statement you are only querying a **single** column. So there is no column with index 1.

Answer (score 1):

You have only one column in select